# SVG path to border radius

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

Is it possible to make such a shape http://grab.by/Efqk using only CSS border-radius?

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9tjgof09/

```
.avatars {
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

.avatars strong {
    display: block;
}
.avatars li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.avatar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.avatars img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.avatar-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.avatar-css img {
    border-radius: 25px/25px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, what have you tried? Please provide your attempted code. You know `border-radius` has multiple values, right? [**MDN  Border-radius**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Comment: Here's what I have at the moment (including SVG code) http://jsfiddle.net/9tjgof09/

Answer (score 2):

you can do all sorts of shapes with css, look at the avatar i put at the bottom of yours, first length to border radius is horiz, second vert. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tjgof09/2/)

```css
#myAvatar{
    border-top-left-radius:5px 25px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px 55px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:30px 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 25px;
}
```

```html
 <img id="myAvatar" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
```

Comment: it doesn't look same

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you need to use more than just border radius. Here is an example:

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/24z7mLc7/)

```
#tv {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
margin: 20px 0;
background: red;
border-radius: 50% / 10%;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-indent: .1em;
}
#tv:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
bottom: 10%;
right: -5%;
left: -5%;
background: inherit;
border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look same http://jsfiddle.net/9tjgof09/